# substrings in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, substring

I have this following piece of code, which returns an error: "Keyerror: False".

```
train["Name"]["Ms." in train["Name"]]
```

Basically, the column "Name" contains a long string with a full name of an individual, including their title (Mr, Mrs, Ms, etc). I want to subselect only the rows which contain a certain title, in this example "Ms.", but I get that error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([['Aaa','bBB'],['Xxx','yYY']],columns=['f','l'])
index=df['f'].str.contains('Aa', regex=False)
df['f'][index]
```